# Python Error in image_to_string

Tags: python, ocr

I'm trying to use the `pytesser` `image_to_string` function but it doesn't work:
The code is:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from pytesser import *
import Image
ImageGrab.grab((0, 0, 900, 500)).save("C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\sss" + '.jpg')
imm= Image.open("C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\sss.jpg")
print image_to_string(imm)
```

It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Project Z\Python\Imagesave\Imagesave\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    text = image_file_to_string('C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\sss.jpg', graceful_errors=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 44, in image_file_to_string
    call_tesseract(filename, scratch_text_name_root)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 21, in call_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato {traduction: Impossible to find specified file}
```

Comment: So where is that file?

Comment: Have you tried using `\\\` for the forward slashes? or using raw strings?

Comment: \\ does not work.
And the file is saved into the desktop every time i run the code